# Vue js: show data from JSON that has date of today only

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my vue JS project, i'm fetching data from JSON API as shown in below format body, and i wanted to show data of `installments` that has date == today only so it should give me city, buyer, paid_amount, remaining, amount, date, flat, and building of the flat that has installment amount registered in the same day of today
is it possible to do it?

```html
      "flats": [
                        {
                            "status": "sold",
                            "price": "550045",
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "end_date": "Not Set",
                            "buyer": "TEST",
                            "buyer_phone_number": "53687225",
                            "receipt_number_field": "0144542",
                            "size_unit": "M",
                            "_id": "61e6bccba5da17be7a90fe2e",
                            "flat_number": 1,
                            "description": "This is a newly created flat.",
                            "city": "NY",
                            "payment": {
                                "installment_payment": {
                                    "installments": [
                                        {
                                            "amount": "52001",
                                            "date": "2022-02-21",
                                            "is_paid": true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "amount": "2500",
                                            "date": "2022-02-13",
                                            "is_paid": false
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "amount": "5522",
                                            "date": "2022-03-05",
                                            "is_paid": false
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "amount": "4555",
                                            "date": "2022-03-02",
                                            "is_paid": false
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "amount": "4444",
                                            "date": "2022-02-24",
                                            "is_paid": false
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "remaining": "498044"
                                },
                                "paid_amount": "52001"
                            },
                            "floor": "61e6bccba5da17be7a90fe2d",
                            "building": "61e6bccba5da17be7a90fe2c",
                            "size": "176.25",
                            "directions": " south",
                            "createdAt": "2022-01-18T13:12:53.212Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-02-21T15:27:36.774Z",
                            "__v": 0
                        },
```

code below in Vue js:

```js
   <b-card-body class="px-lg-5 py-lg-5" v-for="flat in Flats" :key="flat._id" v-show="flat.status=='sold'" >
                                    <div class="text-center text-muted mb-4 border-dash">

                                        <div v-for="find in flat.payment" :key="find._id" v-if="flat.payment.installment_payment && flat.payment.installment_payment.installments[0].date ==currentDate">
                                            <h2>{{flat.buyer}} <i class="fas fa-user"></i> </h2>
                                            <h3 class="mb-5">flat ({{flat.flat_number}})</h3> // i treid this but it's repeated more than one time
                                            <div v-if="flat.payment.installment_payment">

                                                <div v-for="(inst, index2) in find.installments" :key="index2">

                                                    <b-row>

                                                        <b-col>

                                                            <h4 :class="{ 'text-green': inst.is_paid == true, 'text-red': inst.is_paid == 'false'}">{{inst.amount}}$ </h4>
                                                        </b-col>

                                                        <b-col style="left:30px !important;">
                                                            <h4 :class="{ 'text-green': inst.is_paid == true, 'text-red': inst.is_paid == 'false'}">{{inst.date}}

                                                            </h4>
                                                        </b-col>

                                                    </b-row>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                         

                                        </div>

                                        <!---      <p class="city" >{{flat.city}}</p>

                                        <span v-for="(building,index) in Building" :key="index">
                                            <p class="iconB" v-if="building._id.includes(flat.building)">{{building.building_number}} <i class="ni ni-building"></i> </p>

                                        </span>

                                        <h2>{{flat.buyer}} <i class="fas fa-user"></i> </h2>
                                        <h3 class="mb-5">flat ({{flat.flat_number}})</h3>
                                        <h4 v-for="(flatno,index1) in Floors" :key="index1+'ss'" v-if="flatno._id==flat.floor"> floor ({{ flatno.floor_number}}) </h4>
                                        <h4>size ({{flat.size}})</h4>
                                        <h4 class="mb-5">direction ({{flat.directions}})</h4>

                           
                                        <div v-if="flat.payment && flat.payment.installment_payment">
                                            <h3 class="paidText">price: ${{flat.price}}</h3>

                                            <h3 class="paidText mb-3">{{flat.payment.paid_amount}}$ : {{flat.updatedAt | formatDate}} paid</h3>
                                            <h3 class="paidText mb-3"> remaining : ${{flat.payment.installment_payment.remaining}}</h3>
 
                                        </div>-->
                                    </div>
                                    <validation-observer ref="formValidator">

                                    </validation-observer>
                                </b-card-body>
```

i tried code above it gives me the amount with today's date correctly but i have problem with other data cuz it's repeated more than one time for each flat :|

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will only show if the date is the same. Otherwise you can filter your data before displaying it.

```
<div v-for="(inst, index2) in find.installments" :key="index2">
  <b-row v-if="inst.date == new Date()">
    <b-col>
      <h4
        :class="{
          'text-green': inst.is_paid == true,
          'text-red': inst.is_paid == 'false'
        }"
      >
        {{ inst.amount }}$
      </h4>
    </b-col>

    <b-col style="left:30px !important;">
      <h4
        :class="{
          'text-green': inst.is_paid == true,
          'text-red': inst.is_paid == 'false'
        }"
      >
        {{ inst.date }}
      </h4>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you buty i wantd to show other data too related to this instalments like i mentioned above .. for ex buyer , flat and etc